# CSS animation, whats the best approach to this

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm scratching my head on this animation I need to create. I've been briefed on moving a single element like the text in this ["missing" video](https://static01.nyt.com/newsgraphics/2017/05/18/ny-issue/assets/videos/missing-768.mp4)

However, I cant seem to get close to the animation using keyframes and translate x/y like this:

```
 25%  { transform: translate(10px, 10px); }
```

How is best to recreate this movement?

Comment: FWIW the site you linked to is using video.

Comment: https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/jwwebr this help?

Comment: @hungerstar yeah, I need it in css though.

Comment: @MichaelCoker thats sort of what I'm after- its the almost circular motion I'm having an issue with...

Comment: Just add more steps in the animation. You can `rotate()` too https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/jwwebr if that's what you're going for, let me know and I'll submit an answer

Comment: Then you have no code for us to work with and you need to supply the code for this question not to be closed cause SO is not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
@keyframes moveit {
  0%  { transform: translate(0px, 0px); }
  25%  { transform: translate(10px, 10px); }
  50%  { transform: translate(20px, 10px); }
  75%  { transform: translate(10px, 20px); }
  100%  { transform: translate(0px, 0px); }
}
```

It starts without transformation, its original position. Then it moves around and then it comes back. Repeat. You can put more steps to make it move more "randomly" or smoothly.

```
.moveit{ animation: moveit 1s linear infinite; }
```

Play around with the duration (1s) and timing function (linear, ease-in-out, ...) to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Keyframes are a good way to do animation. You can slow it down by making the animation time longer or play around with giving different delays to each letter.

But I'd probably go with something like this.

```css
body {
  background: #3C3C3C;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.missing_animation .letter {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation-name: shakey;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  font-size: 120px;
  color: #3C3C3C;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #FFF, 1px -1px 0 #FFF, -1px 1px 0 #FFF, 1px 1px 0 #FFF;
}

.missing_animation .letter_break {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

.missing_animation .letter:nth-child(even) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes shakey {
  0% {
    transform: translate(1px, .5px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(-.5px, -1px) rotate(-.5deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 0px) rotate(.5deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(0px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(.5px, -.5px) rotate(.5deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-.5px, 1px) rotate(-.5deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, .5px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(1px, .5px) rotate(-.5deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-.5px, -.5px) rotate(.5deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(.5px, -1px) rotate(-.5deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="missing_animation">
  <div class="letter">M</div>
  <div class="letter">I</div>
  <div class="letter">S</div>
  <div class="letter">S</div>
  <div class="letter_break">
    <div class="letter">I</div>
    <div class="letter">N</div>
    <div class="letter">G</div>
  </div>
</div>
```